# @Size(min, max) but not required

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-validator

Hi In my spring webapp I have a password variable which I want to be at least 0 characters or more than 6 and less than 20. I know that there is annotation:

```
 @Size(min=6, max=20)
```

but I have no idea how to add possibility that password can be 0 characters. Will somebody help me with this?

Comment: You want **either** empty password **or** 6 to 20 chars lenght, correct? Are you using hibernate-validator in Spring MVC Controller?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the comment, you can use [`StringTrimmerEditor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/StringTrimmerEditor.html) to convert empty string to null, and then `@Size` check will not trigger (null is considered as valid in @Size).

In your controller add following method:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
}
```

Note that `StringTrimmerEditor` also trims input from spaces, and if you only want one property to be affected by this editor use [`registerCustomEditor(Class<?> requiredType, String propertyPath, PropertyEditor propertyEditor)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/PropertyEditorRegistry.html#registerCustomEditor%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.beans.PropertyEditor%29).

Comment: Its working thanks. But could you write me example of variable propertyPath. Is it just a name of the input or variable in controller?

Answer (score 10):

If you want a String which is either empty ("") or between 6 and 20 characters long, you could specify a regular expression using the `@Pattern` constraint:

```
@Pattern(regexp="(^$|.{6,20})")
```

Comment: I accepted previous answer because it is working and was just earlier, but thank you for this solution.

Comment: Elegant, but you can't get the min and max values in the (localized) messages.

Comment: @PierreHenry that u can generate custom like this @Pattern(regexp="(^$|.{5,15})", message="Length should be between 5 and 15")

Comment: @Gunnar how to avoid blank string in the same pattern?

Comment: I'd suggest to just add a `@NotBlank` constraint next to `@Pattern` (it's part of HV 5.x and part of the Bean Validation 2.0 spec).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a nullable field, but that also could be `min = 6` and `max = 20`. AFAIK, `@Size` should only activate if the field is non-null.

If you're sending an empty string `""`, it will be validated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ConstraintComposition](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e3701), at least in Hibernate Validator 5.