# @Size annotation to validate a field

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, jsr

I need to validate a field - secPhoneNumber (secondary phone #). I need to satisfy below conditions using JSR validation

- The field can be empty/null
- Otherwise, the data must be of length 10.

I tried the code below. The field is always getting validated on form submission.  How do I validate the field to be of length 10 only when it is not empty?

Spring Form:

```
<form:label path="secPhoneNumber">
Secondary phone number <form:errors path="secPhoneNumber" cssClass="error" />
</form:label>
<form:input path="secPhoneNumber" />
```

Bean

```
@Size(max=10,min=10)
    private String secPhoneNumber;
```

Comment: Should me `@Length` for a String. And it is not checked when the value is null.

Comment: Mengelle, Thanks for your input. Tried using @Length(max=10,min=10) private String secPhoneNumber , but doesn't fulfill the use case.

Comment: Sorry, `@Size` was valid with javax.validation, but not hibernate validator. I don't know what you use. Anyway, if your need is : not required, but when provided the length = 10 (it is what i understood), this should be ok. 
Note that an empty string is considered as a value, so the `@Size` will be trigered. You need null value if not provided, then the validation will not be trigerred.  For more details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550324/sizemin-max-but-not-required

Comment: Adjusted code formatting; cleaned up rhetoric.

Answer (score 2):

I think for readability and to use in future times i would create my custom validation class, you only should follow this steps:

1. Add your new custom annotation to your field

   ```
   @notEmptyMinSize(size=10)
   private String secPhoneNumber;
   ```
2. Create the custom validation classes

   ```
   @Documented
   @Constraint(validatedBy = notEmptyMinSize.class)
   @Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   public @interface notEmptyMinSize {


       int size() default 10;

       Class<?>[] groups() default {};

       Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

   }
   ```
3. Add your business logic to your validation

   ```
   public class NotEmptyConstraintValidator implements      ConstraintValidator<notEmptyMinSize, String> {

        private NotEmptyMinSize notEmptyMinSize;

        @Override
        public void initialize(notEmptyMinSize notEmptyMinSize) { 
            this.notEmptyMinSize = notEmptyMinSize
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(String notEmptyField, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
           if(notEmptyField == null) {
                return true;
           }
           return notEmptyField.length() == notEmptyMinSize.size();
       }

   }
   ```

And now you could use this validation in several fields with different sizes.

Here another example you can follow [example](http://outbottle.com/custom-annotated-validation-with-spring-3-web-mvc/)

Answer (score 1):

Following patterns work

1. @Pattern(regexp="^(\s*|[a-zA-Z0-9]{10})$")
2. @Pattern(regexp="^(\s*|\d{10})$")

```
// ^             # Start of the line
// \s*           # A whitespace character, Zero or more times
// \d{10}        # A digit: [0-9], exactly 10 times
//[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}    # a-z,A-Z,0-9, exactly 10 times
// $             # End of the line
```

Reference: [Validate only if the field is not Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262979/validate-only-if-the-field-is-not-null?rq=1)