# Specific size if field have value

Tags: spring-boot

I use spring boot 3, I need to validate some field, I use annotation

I have an field not mandatory, but if user enter value, size need to be 10.

```
@Size(min=10, max = 10)
private String fax;
```

but it's like field came mandatory because min and max is same value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Size annotation to validate a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224733/size-annotation-to-validate-a-field)